# I'm doing an assignment for my class where I need to create the functions below for a Path. I'm having trouble on the functions, am I overthinking it?

Tags: object, arraylist, constructor, java.util.scanner, point

```
import java.awt.Point;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Path 
{
    ArrayList<Point> pointOne;
    ArrayList<Point> pointTwo;
    
    public Path() {
        pointOne = new ArrayList<Point>();
        pointTwo = new ArrayList<Point>();
    }
    
    public Path(Scanner s) 
    {
        pointOne = new ArrayList<Point>();
        pointTwo = new ArrayList<Point>();
        
        
    }
    
    public int getPointCount()
    {
        return 0;
    }
    
    public int getX(int n)
    {
        return n;
    }
    
    public int getY(int n)
    {
        return n;
    }
    
    public void add(int x, int y)
    {
        
    }
    
    public String toString()
    {
        
    }
```

So far this is what I have for the getX and getY function, please feel free to correct me if im not doing something right.

I've tried to research some different ways to add two points to an arraylist. I found one here but it didn't help as much as I thought it was going to. I am also confused on how to use the scanner to scan in the points and build a path. Am I just being dumb and overthinking this? I'm going to talk to my teacher to see if he can clear anything up but any help would be much appreciated thanks

Comment: If you found an answer helpful, please accept (click the check) and upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Main {
    public static void main {
        ArrayList<Point> path = new ArrayList<Point>();
        path.add(new Point(x1,y1));
        path.add(new Point(x2,y2));
    }
}
public class Point {
    private double X;
    private double Y;
    public Point(double x, double y){
       X = x;
       Y = y;
  }
  public double getX(){return X;}
  public double getY(){return Y;}
}
```

You see, a path is a list of points, conceptually, specifically an ArrayList of Points here. Point is a type of object with attributes x and y. You don't need to create an type called Path because a Path is just an `ArrayList<Point>`. You can't extend ArrayLists, probably you don't know yet about how inheritance anyways. But unless you are told specifically to do so, there's no need to make Path a class.

Furthermore, Point could be removed as a type and just made as an `ArrayList<Double>`. Conceptually, a point is just a list of its numeric coordinates in each direction.

Therefore, a Path could be represented as an `ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>>`.